# Matlab - Move Y-Axis to origin?

Tags: matlab, plot

I know that Matlab sometimes isn't the best tool to create "fancy" plots but since my university requires it I dont have much choice.

I want to move the Y-Axis and the "arrow"-Annotation of the following example to x=0.

```
X = -pi/2 : 0.001 : pi/2;
Y = cos(X).^2;
plot(X, Y,'Color',[0,0,1]);

ylim([0 1.2]);
set(gca, 'YTick',[1.2],'yticklabel',{'{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}X(f)}'});
set(gca, 'XTick',[-pi/2,pi/2],'xticklabel',{'-f_{max}' 'f_{max}'});

set(gca,'fontsize',16);
box off;
grid off;
fig_pos=get(gca,'Position');
xp1=fig_pos(1);
xp2=fig_pos(1)+fig_pos(3)+0.02;
yp1=fig_pos(2);
yp2=fig_pos(2)+fig_pos(4)+0.03;
a1=annotation('arrow', [xp1 xp2],[yp1 yp1]);
a2=annotation('arrow', [xp1 xp1],[yp1 yp2]);
```

[image]

I tried to use PlotAxesAtOrigin and axescenter of the FileExchange but due to the annotations this doesn't work properly.

Does anyone know a way to make this work?

Thanks for your help, Klaus!

Comment: Since noone here seems to be able to answer this question (?), does someone maybe know if MATLAB 2015a has some buildin function to move the y-axis? I think with this it would be easier to solve my problem than using the "fileexchange" functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the y-axis arrow annotation is straight forward.  Simply replace your last line with

```
a2=annotation('arrow', fig_pos(1)+fig_pos(3)/2*[1 1],[yp1 yp2]);
```

Moving the `X(f)` is slightly more problematic as you can no longer use the Ytick labels.
Replace your 5th line with

```
set(gca, 'YTick','');
```

and add the following line

```
text(0.1,1.2,'{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}X(f)}','FontSize',16);
```

at the end of the code.

There's no way to remove the black vertical line that is still on the left side of the axes, so you need to *mask* it with another annotation.  Something like

```
annotation('line',fig_pos(1)*[1 1],[fig_pos(2) fig_pos(2)+fig_pos(4)],...
'Color',get(gcf,'Color'),'LineWidth',2);
```

would do.

That gives

[image]

A final note is that you create a variable called `fig_pos`.  That is misleading as it contains the axis position (on the figure), *not* the figure position (which is its position relative to the lower left corner of your monitor).  Your variable should really be called `axis_pos`.

Comment: When selecting "Edit" "Copy Figure" and inserting it in ppt there is still some small malfunction but I think I will be able to handle this. - Thank you alot this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "axis" command, if you know the value of fmax. axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])